# Python Multiprocessing error "Can't pickle <ufunc '<lambda> (vectorized)'>"

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I have a large class that's too large and complex to post here. Within it I have the following two functions:

```
    def test(self):
        print("hji")
    def test2(self):
        p = Process(target=self.test)
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

when I import this class and run test2 from a Jupyter notebook I run into the error

```
135 def test2(self):
    136     p = Process(target=self.test)
--> 137     p.start()
    138     p.join()

File ~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py:121, in BaseProcess.start(self)
    118 assert not _current_process._config.get('daemon'), \
    119        'daemonic processes are not allowed to have children'
    120 _cleanup()
--> 121 self._popen = self._Popen(self)
    122 self._sentinel = self._popen.sentinel
    123 # Avoid a refcycle if the target function holds an indirect
    124 # reference to the process object (see bpo-30775)

File ~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/context.py:224, in Process._Popen(process_obj)
    222 @staticmethod
    223 def _Popen(process_obj):
--> 224     return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
...
     58 def dump(obj, file, protocol=None):
     59     '''Replacement for pickle.dump() using ForkingPickler.'''
---> 60     ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)

PicklingError: Can't pickle <ufunc '<lambda> (vectorized)'>: attribute lookup <lambda> (vectorized) on __main__ failed
```

If I make a second class within the same file I'm importing into Jupyter, and include the test and test2 functions in that class it works as expected without error.

Comment: you might want to try `pathos` instead.

Comment: I've now tried the pathos package and I still run into the error Can't pickle <ufunc '<lambda> (vectorized)'>: it's not found as __main__.<lambda> (vectorized)

Comment: It's likely that the class that you're defining those methods in contains some kind of data that can't be pickled. The error suggests some kind of numpy vectorized thing, but you'd know a lot better than I what data you're storing. If you don't need `test` to be a method (since `print('hji')` doesn't depend on `self` for anything), try moving it out of the class!

Comment: I'm working on an ML implementation. I've done more testing, and the issues comes when I pass my custom Agent class in the "args" for the Process.